# How to add link to pdf with itext to open a remote link on a new tab?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have added a link to pdf with lowagie itext 2.0.8. When i click the link, its working but it opens it in the same page. I want to open it in the new page but i couldnt find how to do. Any way to do it with itext?

```
    PdfAction action = new PdfAction(uri);
    //uri like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
    com.lowagie.text.Rectangle targetArea = checkLinkArea(c, box);
    if (targetArea == null) {
        return;
    }
    PdfAnnotation annot = PdfAnnotation.createLink(
            _writer, targetArea, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT, action);

    annot.setBorderStyle(new PdfBorderDictionary(0.0f, 0));

    _writer.addAnnotation(annot);
```

Comment: Lowagie, that's me, but I don't answer questions about software that was released in January 2008 (which is when iText 2.0.8 was released). Why not? Because a self-respecting company maintains its software, and this includes upgrading versions of libraries that have been declared "End of Life" many years ago.

Comment: Then how can we do it in the new version? I want to open external URL in new tab.(_blank) @BrunoLowagie

Comment: @BrunoLowagie any help for itext 7 version